# Intermittent "Your browser session has expired and we are unable to complete your form submission" errors

Tags: civicontribute

In the midst of a fund drive and we're seeing intermittent instances of the message "Your browser session has expired and we are unable to complete your form submission. We have returned you to the initial step so you can complete and resubmit the form. If you experience continued difficulties, please contact us for assistance." on our contribution page.

This is on WordPress, CiviCRM 5.6, using the latest version of the Stripe plugin.

Nothing jumps out at me in the logs -- I do see some weird permission denied on wp-blog-header.php messages but those don't seem to be related in terms of the timestamp, and the site's behaving fine from what I can tell.

Any ideas on what might be causing this and how best to troubleshoot further? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Based on further investigation and discussion this seems to have been related to the WP Super Cache "Don’t cache pages with GET parameters. (?x=y at the end of a url)" setting being disabled. Once we got a bit of a spike in donors some people started seeing the error, but luckily a donor notified us so we caught it pretty quickly, and I was able to flip back to a Gravity Forms donation form as a stopgap while we did some troubleshooting. Live and learn.