# CiviContribute Session timeout

Tags: drupal, civicontribute

We are using tablets to sign up new members on the street, but are getting the following error:

> Your browser session has expired and we are unable to complete your form submission. We have returned you to the initial step so you can complete and resubmit the form. If you experience continued difficulties, please contact us for assistance.

It's a similar problem to [Intermittent "Your browser session has expired and we are unable to complete your form submission" errors](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27182/intermittent-your-browser-session-has-expired-and-we-are-unable-to-complete-you), but we're on CiviCRM 5.7.6 and Drupal 7.67.

Is it possible to change these timeout settings?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: How often is it happening? Drupal 7 has a default timeout in drupal's settings.php but it's quite long so that might not be the problem, but you can change it to 0 for unlimited just to see if it fixes it. (https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/7.x/sites/default/default.settings.php#L331)

Comment: Thanks for the input! Yes this could be it. The page is open while our canvasser has a conversation with the new member, so it will likely be 10+ minutes. It works fine for regular web use.

Comment: The default drupal one is much longer than that so I'm not sure it's the problem. Check also if you have any 3rd party autologout drupal modules enabled.